# Can AWS Lambda execute Spring Boot application implemented using command line runner?

Tags: java, spring-boot, aws-lambda

My spring boot application implemented using command line runner (meaning it's not an API) is executed using java -jar with bunch of command line arguments. We have been running our application manually on AWS EC2 so far and now in an attempt to Automate application execution we have started a POC using Lambda. Lambda is chosen because application must trigger at SNS event (which is for file upload event in S3).

I have configured lambda function using Java runtime and attached it to SNS topic. Lambda is successfully triggered and sending a call to my application Jar which is uploaded in lambda function through S3.
Application first step is to download the file from S3, so I am implementing LambdaHandler class using S3 event, as shown below.

```
public class LambdaHandler implements RequestHandler<S3Event, String> {
// Code to fetch S3 object name here which is needed in application processing logic further
}
```

I am unable to figure out how to initialize spring boot batch application which is implemented using command line runner, is this even possible?
Would you recommend an alternate approach (Jenkins connecting to EC2 and running a bash script to download file from S3 then wget jar file from artifactory and run java -jar build command to execute)

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem (http://xyproblem.info/). Rather than jump to a conclusion that you need a Lambda that runs a Spring Boot application, instead ask us for possible solutions to your real problem.

Comment: Running a spring boot application seems very off for a Lambda. Lambdas are desinged to be lightweight executions. Keep in mind that you pay for every 100ms of execution, thus having a low exeuction time is beneficial to you. Amazon does "freeze" the JVM after execution, however from my experience, the "frozen" JVM is discarded after some time and when the next exeuction is triggered, the whole JVM has to be reinitialized (including your boot application).

Comment: @Jason - updated my ask in question, do you have a suggestion/solution for it?

Comment: @Turing85 - If it was an API in spring boot and response time was a concern, I would not have chosen Lambda for execution. Since it's a stand alone Java application which will definitely finish execution before 15 min max lambda timeout period, I do not mind Lambda. Application will be triggered once a day only, so lambda's cold start is not a problem in our case.  What do you suggest?

Comment: @inCode I cannot suggest anything since I do not know what your exact problem is. As of now, I fail to see the benefit you get from Spring boot (due to the fact I do not know what your usecase is).

Comment: Were you able to find something on this or you moved away from spring boot to normal java app with maven?